# What's the opposite of the "mesh" of a partition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, partitions-for-integration

The *mesh* of a partition of an interval is defined as the maximum distance between two consecutive points of the partition,
$$
\operatorname{mesh}(P) := \max_{i\ge 1}(x_i-x_{i-1}) \quad\text{where \( P = (x_0, x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \) and \( x_0 < x_1 < \dotsb < x_n \)}.
$$
I was wondering if there is a specific terminology for the *minimum* such distance, $ \min_{i\ge 1}(x_i-x_{i-1}) $.

Thank you for any answer or insight you may have.

Comment: Should be $\min_{i\ge1} (x_i-x_{i-1})$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS Fixed it, ty.